# Invoke private method by reflection in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection

I need to invoke a private method and pass param to it. The standard way it is using reflection. There are a lot of technics and it's possible in Kotlin, Java, C#.
However, what do I need to call in Swift to achieve the expected result? The sample code is below:

```
class Test {
    private func doSomething(value: String) {
    }
}

let testInstance = Test()
// how to invoke private method and pass param
testInstance.doSomething("Hello world!")
```

Comment: You could try to check out `Mirror`, which is reflection in Swift. You can read private properties if I recall correctly, but not write them. I am not sure about private methods.

Comment: Swift does not have a strong support for reflection so this is not the solution, if you are writing unit tests then you should be calling the public methods of your test object anyway.

Comment: I use Mirror object for access to private fields and able to modify state in case if field is a reference type. However, I still can't do anything with private methods. I believe there is a possibility to invoke private methods via Objective-C but it is not applicable for me.

Comment: Why do you need to access private methods? The methods are private for a reason, they are part of the internal kitchen of the class, and should not be directly called.